# User can answer to a question marked as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

I was making an answer to a question in SO on (03-Jan-2014) and while I was making my answer I got a pop up saying that this question is closed now....and so on.. And when I checked the `POST YOUR ANSWER` button it looks like a disabled one.And when I inspected the html of that button its like the following

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Answer" tabindex="110" disabled="disabled">
```

So I simply removed the disabled attribute of that element and made it as this

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Answer" tabindex="110">
```

which made the element a normal one.Then I completed my answer and posted it. And the answer has posted even if the question was marked as a duplicate. You can check the following link to see the question and its answer

[PHP: For vs. Foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902118/php-for-vs-foreach/20902244)

And when you check the question you can see that the answer is posted after 3 mins the question is closed which proves what I stated.

Comment: Yes, the server side validation has a grace period. After that you couldn't post an answer even if you change the HTML.

Comment: Yeah right.. But whats the point behind the lag in server side validation.? I am asking just becusae of curiosity..